# Testing for focused element with jest 25.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, focus, enzyme

We use jest tests with `expect(document.activeElement).toBe(myElement)` pattern to determine if an element got correctly focused after an interaction. After upgrading to jest 25 (jsdom 15) all such tests broke, `document.activeElement` appears to be always `null`.

For example the following test works with Jest 24.x but not with 25.x

```js
// example.spec.js
import * as React from 'react';

it('should find active element', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<input />);
    const inputNode = wrapper.find('input').getDOMNode();
    inputNode.focus();
    expect(document.activeElement).toBe(inputNode); // fails with 'expected' being null
});
```

What is the best way to test if an element is focused using Jest 25.x?

Comment: Can you use `jest-dom` - https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavefocus

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. It is a nice lib, but under the hood it still checks for `document.activeElement` (or to be precise for `node.ownerDocument.activeElement`) which is still `null`. So it doesn't fix the tests.

Comment: This was cross-posted to GitHub here: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2924